# Why is sudo dpkg -i filename.deb not working?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run the following in the command line:

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

And it's not working. Should I install any package?

Please advice?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's not a broken package, Check the dependencies with sudo dpkg -i filename.deb and apt-get install the dependencies before dpkg -i filename.deb.
You can find more here :  https://help.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/desktopguide/ru/manual-install.html.

Comment: when trying to install it is stating : dependency problems prevent configuration of unifi video . so what should I do ?

Answer (score -1):

Use following step command :

//added repository for installing package

```
sudo  add-apt-repository '<package>'
```

After that use update command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: How on earth is this related to the question?!

Comment: This is "filename.deb" package solution, this is general solution if deb not found error occurs. 
also for above file "filename.deb"  (package) is not valid path so i mention global solution .

Comment: Since when does `add-apt-repository` work with `.deb` files?! And what is it supposed to do? A repository and a package are _very_ different things.

Comment: Biffen, I just want to store package using added repository, when we got error "deb command not found"
As the above question is not clear so i just suggest !.